# How insert multiple rows in three different table at a time through procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

If I want to insert multiple rows in three different table A, B , C at a time through procedure in mysql but error comes when data is inserted in " C " table and data is not insert in table " C " but data is inserted in table " A " and " B ".
Now how i can rollback for table A and B and how i put exception log that data is not inserted in table
 " C ".

Comment: Do you want us to write the whole script for you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `set autocommit=0` before executing any query.

after that call store procedure,if there is an error found in store procedure do not call

`Con.Commmit()` con is object of Connection class.

If Store procedure ran smoothly then call Con.Commit() this will affect in all the table you no need to rollback it.